# Magento2 Back in stock mail is taking wrong from name and from email

Tags: magento2

Magento2.2.7 I am facing a strange issue.

The site is multi-store

when a mail is fired for Back-in-stock products at that time the Form Name & Form Email is taken from the Base store & not from the one mentioned for a particular store.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Already installed MDVA-10993_EE_2.2.4_v1.composer.patch from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952